# What is the efficient way to search trough NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, prefix-tree

I have NSStrings in my array:

```
i[0] = axxx
i[1] = axyz
i[2] = axxy
i[3] = abcd
```

I want to pass a search string to find all needed strings. For example if I pass "ax" then it will return 3 strings, if I pass "axx" then it will return 2 string.

Performance is critical here as well. The method should look like this:

```
- (NSArray *)searchString:(NSString *)search;
```

Noramlly I use `NSPredicate`, but this time I need to use maybe Prefix Tree or Binary Tree, I am not sure but it should be faster. Any suggestion or links to implementation.

Comment: If the array is sorted, the fastest you'll get is a binary search.  If not, the best you can do is linear.  The other data structures may fair slightly better than binary search, but probably not enough to matter.

Comment: Additionally, `NSPredicate` is a method of matching elements.  It doesn't describe the traversal through the container, which is what your question is really about.

Comment: You should learn giving your methods good names. "searchString:" is completely meaningless. If you intend to return an array with all strings having a certain prefix, call it "stringsWithPrefix:"

Comment: "I am not sure but it should be faster": 1. Make it work. 2. If it's not fast enough, measure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this solution will satisfy you.

```
- (NSArray *)searchString:(NSString *)search{

    NSIndexSet *indexes = [dataArray indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:
                           ^BOOL (id obj, NSUInteger i, BOOL *stop) {
                               NSString *myObj = obj;
                               return [myObj containsString:search];
                           }];
    NSArray *results = [dataArray objectsAtIndexes:indexes];

    return results;

}
```

Comment: It will work for prefix as well as for substring. Are you only looking for prefix?

Comment: I am looking for prefix and substring or full string

Comment: then it will work for you. Hopefully you will give me credit after trying this in your code ;)

Comment: get stuck with 10000 object in array)

Comment: but yea it works, and how actually look trough prefix only for example if I have string bbax and axbb and I am looking for ax, then it should return only 1 object?

Comment: You just need to change condition for this

`NSString *myObj = obj;
                               
                               if (myObj.length >= search.length) {
                                   return [[[myObj substringFromIndex:0] substringToIndex:search.length] containsString:search];
                               }else{
                                   return false;
                               }`

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly simple problem.

As Avi suggests in his comment, there's 2 parts to it: The method you use for matching, and the method you use for searching for those matches.

If your array is sorted and you're looking for a single, perfect match, you can use a binary search. I believe that will give you O(log(n)) performance. (Time goes up with the log of the number of elements.)

However, you're not looking for a single, perfect match. You're looking for partial matches. If they always must match the beginning of the string then you still might be able to use a binary search to find the first match, and then search linearly up and down in the array until the first non-match. That will give you slightly worse than O(log(n)) performance, but not as bad as O(n).

If you are matching your substring anywhere inside the entries I think you're going to have to test every element in the array. You will simply need to test every element, giving you O(n) performance.

Note that O(n) performance is generally considered good. It scales well for large data-sets. (You want to avoid O(n^2) performance. That's what kills you.)

The second part of the problem is matching speed. You can probably get slightly better performance than a predicate by writing your own string matching routine that is hard-coded for your exact match criteria, but the performance gains are likely to be modest. You would have to give more details about what constitutes a match in order for us to help with this part.

Comment: It's not sorted array and I need to search even if I have string bbbbaxxyz, so it this case ax prefix is not at start of line. what you can suggest then? thanks!)

Comment: Do you need to do a case-insensitive search? (If you're searching for "ax" and the the entry is "BBBAXMMM", should it match? What about diacritical marks? (Say your search string is "red". Should "xxxréd" match?

Comment: The best you're going to get is linear (O(n)) performance. You can try to hand-code your match function for speed, but you need to be very specific about what is and is not a match. See my additional questions.

Answer (score 0):

There is essential information missing. If you look for "axx", do you expect "haxx" to be in your results? "HaXX"? "Axxyyyz"? "äxx"? How many strings do you have? 10? 100? 1000? 100,000? How often do you do this search? How often does the array change?

First step is to figure out which NSString method will match the strings you want to match. Second step is to implement using brute force and measuring (predicates are usually several times slower than looping through the array). Third step is to figure out whether sorting the data can help.

Comment: "haxx" to be in your results? "HaXX"? "Axxyyyz"? "äxx"? - we can skip it. it could be 100 000 and I can do search very often and array can't be changed. thanks)